# Replacement for IExpandProvider

Tags: wcf-data-services

I'm trying to create an OData WCF service using NHibernate and I'd like to use `$expand` in queries. I found an interface `IExpandProvider`, which I guess, is (was) exactly for this purpose. But it says `The IExpandProvider interface is deprecated.` What's the current way to implement expand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with V2 the IExpandProvider is deprecated because it can't support the new query options, like $select. The "new" way is to implement IQueryable. All the query options are translated into LINQ expression trees. If you want a bit more detail on how that is done see this series: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2010/02/25/data-services-expressions-part-1-intro.aspx. The part talking about $expand is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vitek/archive/2010/07/15/data-services-expressions-part-9-expansions.aspx

Comment: So, in order to eagerly load related entities that are requested with $expand I have to load them in the getter of the IQueryable<T> property. E.g. https://github.com/PeteGoo/NHibernate.QueryService/blob/master/NHibernateQueryService.Model/NHibernateContext.cs

Comment: Actually no. The IQ<T> property getter only returns an instance of the queryable. This acts as a "storage" for the query. The WCF DS will use that to build the query (might call CreateQuery several times and so on). Once the entire query is built there will be an instance of IQueryable<T> on which the WCF DS will call GetEnumerator. That is the actual execution of the query at which point the expression tree contains the entire query. And that would be the point to deal with expansions (and the rest of the query as well).

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work if I have to start visiting expression trees, because returning `IQueryable<T>` works already except that `$expand` causes lazy loading issues like `select n+1`. Is there any interface or method to override or something just to extend that one feature?

Comment: There's no other way currently. The short answer is, that if the $expand doesn't work, it's a problem of the IQueryable implementation you're using, since it doesn't fulfill the required query correctly (otherwise the $expand would work). And so the way to fix that is to fix the IQueryable.

Comment: The reason for not using IExpandProvider is that it doesn't work with projections ($select) as it can only expand entire entity, not just some of its properties. That said, if you want something like it, it's not that hard to write a visitor which will find the projections in the expression tree and effectively tell you which properties to expand.